# Global object onStart fails all my tests

Tags: testing, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I had a number of tests, it ran perfectly, untill I write Global object:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        Mails.plugin = app.plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
        Mails.from = app.configuration().getString("smtp.from");
        if (Mails.plugin != null) Logger.info("Mailer plugin successfully loaded"); 
        if (Mails.from != null) Logger.info("Mail account is " + Mails.from);

    }
```

Here I am loading plugin for email messages. Now when I try to run my fakeApplication with inMemoryDatabase I get a null pointer exception. Probably it is becouse fakeApplication don't use configuration file, and can't load configuration from this file. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution , for this reason I create fake Global class (or you also can mock it):

```
class Global extends GlobalSettings{

}
```

and Then can pass it:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void startApp() { 
        app = Helpers.fakeApplication(new Global());
        Helpers.start(app);
    }
```

Comment: The method `Helpers.fakeApplication(Global)` does not exist in Play 2.0. If you remove the tag `playframework-2.0` from this question, you'll feel slightly better for marking your own answer as the winner one :-D

Answer (score 2):

Try adding custom config parameters in your `FakeApplication`:

```
Map<String, Object> additionalConfiguration = new HashMap<String, Object>();
additionalConfiguration.put("smtp.from", "foo@bar.com");

running(fakeApplication(additionalConfiguration), new Runnable() {
...
```

Comment: Unfortunatly there is no constructor fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase,myMap)

Comment: I add all properties, but also have an exception, may be plugin isn't loaded ? How to load it using this map?